# "the depth of his reaction to the latter's"

Tags: possessives

*Reading Scholem's  historical writings along with his letters to Benjamin, we begin to understand  the depth of his reaction to the latter's leftward turn.*

Could you please clarify to me why there is an apostrophe in the word "latter". Does this mean the same as *to his (Benjamin's) latter leftward turn?* To tell the truth I am not familiar with the usage of the apostrophe in adjectives. Is it standard in English? Based on the same pattern we can write/tell: John broke the window. I am really upset by terrible's behaviour (by his bad behaviour) which is probably nonsense.

Comment: The Saxon genitive **'s** is because ***the latter*** is a substitution for *...his reaction to **Benjamin's** leftward turn*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on the OP's now-resolved misunderstanding that latter was being used as an adjective. See [OP's comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81080/the-depth-of-his-reaction-to-the-latters#comment157188_81084)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am not familiar with the usage of the apostrophe in adjectives.

In this case, *latter* is *not* an adjective. [*Latter* here is a noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/latter_2):

> **latter** *noun*
>
> **the latter** (pl. **the latter**) the second of two things or people mentioned
>
> - *He presented two solutions. The latter seems much better.*

In this context, *the latter* is a noun phrase meaning *Benjamin*, so *the latter's* means *Benjamin's*.

Answer (score 1):

"Latter" in your case is a **substitution** for whatever was the latter of the two people listed (and that thing is a **noun**; in this case, *Benjamin*) mentioned beforehand. Dictionaries don't cover this usage.

Thus you can use the possessive marker "-'s" on "latter" because it is filling in for a noun (Benjamin).

Same goes with "former" when used to contrast with "latter".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In that case I misunderstood the meaning of the "latter" since I understood it in the sense "later". But your reading of the passage confuses me a little bit. You are writing that "the latter" substitutes Benjamin but isn't it actually "letters to Benjamin" what is substituted? The first mentioned thing is his political writings and the second  letters to Benjamin…

Comment: "The latter" almost always refers to a person.  I'm not sure why, but that does seem to be the case.  Also, interpreting "the latter" as "the letters to Benjamin" doesn't make sense - Scholem had a reaction to his own letters' leftward turn?!

Comment: @stangdon I may fix that soon.

Comment: That's the reason why I interpret the latter's as what happened late, i.e. Benjamin's later turn to the left.

Comment: @bart-leby: antecedents can be semantic; they don't have to be strictly on the grammatical level.   *John's parties are fun and Mike's parties always have great food, but I prefer the former's friends.*

Comment: To be perfectly clear, because nobody has yet, the sentence with the substitution put into effect would be: *Reading Scholem's historical writings along with his letters to Benjamin, we begin to understand the depth of his reaction to Benjamin's leftward turn.*

Comment: @bart If I understand the policy or norm, shouldn't this question be closed or re-phrased since it was based on a misunderstanding that you identify above, and turned into a quite different question in a comment?

Comment: I think that my question had two components. The first one was that I was not sure whether the latter means last mentioned or later and the second one stemmed from my ignorance that – as Tromano explained –  "antecedents can be semantic; they don't have to be strictly on the grammatical level" so I wrongly supposed that  the last mentioned thing was not Benjamin but the letters. Thus the sentence did not make much sense for me. If you find my question irelevant or stupid, I apologize.